# .Net File.Exists - C# vs. PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to test if the Active Directory Administrative Center executable is present.
Path: C:\Windows\System32\dsac.exe
C# (.NET 4.7.2) and PowerShell (5/7) give different results:

- PowerShell claims the file exists (correct)
- C# claims the file does not exist (incorrect)

Using [System.IO.File]::Exists vs Test-Path in PowerShell does not change the result.
All programs have been started with the same credentials.
The credentials used have permissions to read the folder and file.

As this "basic" of a function usually doesn't fail I am at a loss what the issue could be.

Execution results (all started/logged in/executed with the same account):

[image: PowerShell 5]

[image: PowerShell 7]

[image: C#]

[image: File Explorer]

Comment: That's in the interactive shell. Have you tried a simple console program with only that line and a Console.WriteLine of the result?

Comment: Is the interactive shell running as a 32-bit process? [File system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) might be at play here.

Comment: This is most likely a 32 bit vs 64 bit problem. See https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/191104-fileexist-not-working-properly/